# Packet sniffing with channel hopping using scapy

Tags: raspberry-pi, scapy, sniffing

I have set up scapy on linux (raspian on RPI) for sniffing WiFi packets using WiFi adapter (b/g) in monitor mode. I am not sure if scapy by default hops on all the channels of the b/g protocol, or sticks to just one of them.

I'd like to have the capability to sniff different channels by hopping on to them, and to have capability to configure the dwell time on each channel, all using snapy. Can some one help me how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

No, Scapy won't do channel hopping for you.

I don't think Scapy has a way to control your interface's channel, but you might have a job (outside your script or `fork()`-ed from it) that would do something like

```
import os
import time
chans = [1,6,11]
wait = 1
i = 0
while True:
    os.system('iw dev monitor0 set channel %d' % chans[i])
    i = (i + 1) % len(chans)
    time.sleep(wait)
```

Or something with `subprocess.call()` instead of `os.system` if you prefer.

Comment: if I had set up monitor mode using "airmon-ng start wlan0" it creates the interface mon0 in monitor mode but that is tied to the channel/frequency that wlan0 is on, which in turn is connected to a router serving as the Access Point. I have found that I can start hopping around channels if I take down wlan0, but if I need to stay connected to the internet on wlan0 in order to send data to my server is it possible to hop channels on mon0 independent from wlan0 / the AP?

Comment: No it's not, since wlan0 and mon0 are the same physical device and share the same radio. But that's another question ;-)

Comment: New Question :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862077/connect-to-internet-using-wlan0-and-channel-hopping-mon0-as-monitor/28862511#28862511

Comment: And see, you've got a great answer! ;-) (BTW, you should probably upvote Guy Harris answer beside accepting it, since it's a good answer and has helped you).

Comment: I upvote anything I read and find useful (your question, his answer, etc.) because it costs nothing and rewards people sharing their knowledge (asking a smart question is sharing knowledge). I don't know if it's SO etiquette, but it seems OK to me.